# Bitwise AND of a series of random numbers (efficiency)

Tags: bit-manipulation

Given a series of random numbers in an array, e.g.: `147, 95, 254, 78, 66, 120`, how do I find the result of operands from index `n` to index `m` when they're `&`ed (bitwise &) efficiently?

For example:

`n = 2` and `m = 5`. This means you have to `&` the numbers in the array from the second element (`95`) until the fifth element (`66`).

I don't know how other than to just `&` them one by one, but this isn't efficient. The question I'm working with has multiple queries, meaning that with one series of random numbers (for example the above), the question may ask multiple times the `&` result of the numbers from the `n` element until the `m` element with each query containing a different value of `n` and `m`.

---

**EDIT**: I've tried doing the following: change all the numbers into binary bits and store all the bits in deques. Afterwards, check if one of the bits are 0 in the given range, and if there is one 0, then said bit returns 0 value. I did get a correct answer. However, it's still not efficient enough. [Here](https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/3e408c9d94d24447076cb82d81966113) is my code

Comment: One by one is usually fine. If you expect that `0` will be a common result, and the list is large, you *might* want to test whether you get `0` at each step, but that adds an extra branch point - so if `0` *isn't* very common it is probably faster *in the common case* to just not bother (you'd need to profile to be sure).  Can you be a bit more specific about this specific `n`/`m` scenario? it isn't very clear to me (and I do a *lot* of bitwise stuff)

Comment: Ah sorry for confusing you, I'll edit the question, one moment.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi! I tried finishing my version of the code. Unfortunately, it's still not efficient enough, mind helping me?

Comment: I would use a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). Built in O(n log n) time.

Comment: What is the range of the random input? And is there an assumption of architecture, or must it be pure C? I can do this very quickly in AVX-512.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with k range-sum-queries where k is the size of the elements in bits:

For each bit-position, do a range-sum-query. If the result is less than the length of the span, this bit is zero in the result, otherwise it is one. These can be done very easily with k prefix sum arrays, though of course these are fairly large to store compared to the input.

So to be clear, the idea there is to have a prefix-sum array for *just the least significant bit* of every element (and the queries done on it compute the lsb of the result) and an other one for *just the second bit*, and so on, up to k.

Prefix-AND arrays cannot be used in the same way, for example consider if the first element is zero, but a word-level alternative that *does* work is a sideways heap. This would take only one actual query (which is more complex though), and only about double the space of the input (though rounded up to a power of two). This requires a fancy "two-sided query" where you go up the tree from two leaves in lock-step and stop when they meet at their LCA (at that point the range between the endpoints is covered and nothing more). More information [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153753/555045).

Both options are probably only useful for competitive programming where they intentionally make the naive algorithm choke on crazy large queries.

Comment: It is indeed for competitive programming. I'm still a total novice and I wonder how do experienced people like you figure out methods like these? I'll try to study what you mean first for the moment >.<

Comment: @WealthyPlayer mainly, if you do a bunch of CP, you start noticing a bunch of patterns, for example for bitwise problems it often (though not always) helps to try to answer the original question separately for each bit and then merge the results

Comment: "... answer the original question separately for each bit..." Does this mean that it might help sometimes when I solve each test case and try to figure out the whole solution to the question (I'm having trouble understanding your statement, I guess I should rest)? Also, I will totally find it more helpful if you can explain more about your answer >.< I'm seriously not grasping what you're trying to say.

Comment: I mean split the problem into k problems if you have k bit wide elements, where each new problem only deals with a single bit of the result. BTW I have some related stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153753/555045), it was for bitwise OR but OR and AND are very closely related (like min vs max)